# PyCharm can not solve RandomState

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pycharm

Python 3.4, numpy 1.9.2, My PyCharm can not solve RandomState. Like:

`from numpy.random.mtrand import RandomState`

I got red underline below `RandomState`

But things are going well when I use Python 2.7

I have tried to reinstall numpy and reload python interpreter, but still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: No, but I have reported this issue to JetBrain, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-15912, according to the feedback on the page, the 2016.2 version has fixed this problem. So have a try?